# VNC ERROR on web

Tags: java, html, ruby-on-rails, applet

Can someone help me to solve my problem regarding to VNC in web.
Kindly refer to the attached image thank you.

[image: Error I got on VNC![][1]]![enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4LkY.jpg)

Comment: read the reason on the error message dialog

Comment: I already read, I dont know how to solved. Thanx in replying

Comment: Either you decrease the level of security in the JVM , either you use signed applets. See [Java Applet & Web Start - Code Signing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html)

Comment: I already change the permission to High. But still same error. Or maybe my site ssl already expired?

Comment: What does this have to do with Rails? With HTML?

Comment: **Don't post images of text.**  I can't read that at the size it appears here, and the SO search engine cannot index it. *"I already change the permission to High."*  There is 'High' security but not 'High' permissions.  Plus, stuffing with the security levels on your own machine is pointless (and not recommended). Surely you don't expect each end user to alter the security level of their JVM.  IF you do, shame on you!